# android tv box hdmi True 3D output for 3D TV

Tags: java, android, 3d

I am planning to buy sony 32" Ex72, 3D TV. I have android mini PC TV box with HDMI Port (as show http://www.dhgate.com/product/latest-tv-box-mk809-iii-rockchip-rk3188-quad/163036566.html).

How can I create 3D programs/games for android TV Box, to output true 3D for 3D TVs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the Mali-400 GPU supports 3D output.
I'm struggling to enable stereo 3D output on my Ouya, with an Nvidia Tegra 3 that in theory does support stereo-3D and indeed it does with some tablets

Comment: ok, but if device support stereo 3D output, how to do it in android SDK ?

Comment: it's vendor specific, here's the documentation for Nvidia: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/whitepapers/2010/3D_Vision_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf